# Android - instead of launch new intent to new class/activity, how go back to open activity/class?

Tags: java, android

My code allows me to launch a new activity/class:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class); 
startActivity(intent); 
finish();
```

What if i have an activity already open, and just want to go back to it instead of reopening a new one, thus having multiple open of same.. So i want to switch back to an already open activity/class ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity1.this, activity2.class); 
intent .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same thing. Android OS doesn't create 2 different versions of your activity, it works with already created activities.

Comment: without finish() it will create endless amounts of the same activity, this is what led me to using finish()... BUT I can have one open already.launch new activity with old activity in the intent at end of new activity and it will have more than one of the same activity open...

Comment: @David, startActivity() means to call onStart method, not onCreate

Answer (score 0):

Really simple:

```
finish();
```

If you want to choose an already existing activity in the backstack and not simply the latest opened that will be more complex and I don't know if you can modify the normal application workflow

Comment: for some reason on my 1st(main) activity/class when I use intent to it from other activity it ends up with 2 of the same layouts/activity open.. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Add this

```
FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT to your Intent you use with startActivity() .
```

Also remove finish()

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT(what goes here?); ??

Comment: Nothing goes there you just set the flag for the intent like this.. intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT;

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting you right, you need to use Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT flag. In this case your activity, if it was created before, will be brought to the front. As [documentation states](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html),

> If set in an Intent passed to Context.startActivity(), 
>   this flag will cause the launched activity to be brought 
>   to the front of its task's history stack if it is already running.

Comment: Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT(this); ? <OR> ); intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: Second option. Like: `Intent preferencesIntent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
            preferencesIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
            startActivity(preferencesIntent);`